# UNIX file read and writing over not writing

Tags: c++, c, file, unix

I'm trying to find a hit in a file and modify it by writing over. But the modification of the field `Effectue` (from the structure `TRAVAIL`) is not applying. I checked that I was replacing the right occur (commented part) but when I call again the function I'm still getting the first occurence with `Effectue` set to `false`.

```
TRAVAIL RechercheProchainTravail() {
    int i, fp;
    TRAVAIL travailRetour;

    if ((fp = open("Travaux.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0664)) == -1) {
        perror("Err open Travaux.dat");
        exit(1);
    }

    // init
    for (i = 0; TravauxInit[i].IndiceLieu > 0; i++)
        write(fp, &TravauxInit[i], sizeof(TRAVAIL));

    // remise au debut
    lseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //lecture
    for (i = 0; TravauxInit[i].IndiceLieu > 0; i++) {
        read(fp, &travailRetour, sizeof(TRAVAIL));
        if (travailRetour.Effectue == false) {
            travailRetour.Effectue = true;
            lseek(fp, -sizeof(TRAVAIL), SEEK_CUR);
            /*read(fp, &travailRetour, sizeof(TRAVAIL));
            Trace(" indice; %d effect %d", travailRetour.IndiceLieu, travailRetour.Effectue);
            lseek(fp, -sizeof(TRAVAIL), SEEK_CUR);*/
            write(fp, &travailRetour, sizeof(TRAVAIL)); 
            break;
        }
    }
    close(fp);

    return travailRetour;
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I changed the open to prevent the file from being truncated as peter noticed, but the issue is still the same, I still access the first occurence because the write don't change the Effectue field value.

Here is my code edit:

```
    if (access( "Travaux.dat", F_OK ) != -1) { // si existe ouvrir
        if ((fp = open("Travaux.dat", O_RDWR, 0664)) == -1) {
            perror("Err open Travaux.dat");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else { // sinon creer
        if ((fp = open("Travaux.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0664)) == -1) {
            perror("Err open Travaux.dat");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

And it is not a `lseek` issue, because the read test displays the right occurrence.

Comment: Are you sure you're not reinitializing the whole file when you call the function again, as your current code shows?

Comment: Since `off_t`  is signed and `size_t` is not, passing `-sizeof(TRAVAIL)` as the second argument to `lseek()` is either wrong or implementation-defined.

Comment: Oh yes sure Peter you are right I totally forgot that the file would be initialized each time, I feal stupid :p

Comment: Did you apply the fix for the `lseek` argument?  I do not understand your remark: *the read test displays the right occurrence*... You seem to mean that you find the correct entry, but it does not get updated correctly.  You do not test the return values of any of the `read`, `write` or `lseek` system calls, how can you tell if anything goes wrong?

Comment: I applied the fix for lseek, but it doesn't change anything, You right, I' m going to test te read write & lseek

Comment: Ok so I tested everything but nothing goes wrong, I don't have any error messages

Comment: Your file access sounds fine, especially since the immediate read works.  Post a full example that demonstrates the error you see on the second time through, so others can try to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a potential problem with this:

```
lseek(fp, -sizeof(TRAVAIL), SEEK_CUR);
```

If `size_t` is smaller than `off_t`, `-sizeof(TRAVAIL)` is a large unsigned value (`SIZE_MAX - sizeof(TRAVAIL) + 1`) that gets converted to `off_t` as such, and not the negative value you expect to seek backwards by one structure.

You can fix it this way:

```
lseek(fp, -(off_t)sizeof(TRAVAIL), SEEK_CUR);
```

Furthermore, you should check the return values of the `read`, `write` and `lseek` system calls to ensure everything goes as expected.

Also add the flag `O_BINARY` if you are compiling for Windows.

Comment: It is implementation defined, no matter how it is related to `long`. And `lseek` takes an `off_t`, which is not necessarily `long`.

Comment: @Olaf: good point about `off_t`, but if `sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(off_t)` the problem is not implementation dependent (except maybe for the pathological case of well chosen numbers of padding bits).

Comment: Hmm, I thought about the negation. But seems you are right, that is well defined for an unsigned integer. (Still, I'd argument with `SIZE_MAX` etc. instead of `sizeof` - this avoids any padding bit problems:-)

Comment: I've tried everything you said but the problem stays the same, I don't have any error

Comment: @RémiHirtz: how do you define `true` and `false` ?

Comment: I'm not defining it, they are bool type

Comment: @RémiHirtz: do you include `<stdbool.h>` or do you use C++?

Comment: I use c++ so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @RémiHirtz:  You should post a complete compilable example that demonstrates the problem.  The type definitions might hide some crutial information to explain the observed behavior.